# In the female reproductive system, is the labia minora / labia majora / labia as a whole the female counterpart of the scrotum in male?

Tags: human-biology, reproduction

I am confused about which labia is the counterpart of the male scrotum. Any help would be appreciated. My first question so pls try being more lenient with downvotes.

Comment: We have an expectation here, as is common across StackExchange, that questions contain evidence of prior research. An example here might be quoting from (and citing) a textbook or other source like Wikipedia that states this homology but is unclear about the details you request. We also ask that questions be free from "meta" information like that it's your "first question": we're building a repository of Q&A here, so ultimately who asks a question isn't supposed to matter, just the content itself; other text is just noise for the next person who finds this Q&A via Google or elsewhere.

Comment: https://www.kenhub.com/en/library/anatomy/homology-of-the-male-and-female-genitalia